# Trouble Overriding CSS Variables in Sanity.io

Tags: sanity

I am attempting to change the styling of Sanity Studio as noted here in the docs:  https://www.sanity.io/docs/styling#d7f9b5cc2adb

As such, I have created a file with the following css variables:

```
@import "part:@sanity/base/theme/variables/gray-colors-style";

:root {
  --fieldset-border: none;
  --fieldset-bg: var(--gray-darker);
}
```

Now, this works as I want for `--fieldset-border`, but it does not work for `--fieldset-bg`.  I even tried hard-coding the value of `--fieldset-bg` as follows:  `--fieldset-bg: #454545;` -- it still did not work.

So, I am wondering, why does `--fieldset-border` work and `--fieldset-bg` not work.  More importantly, what do I have to do so that I can change the background color of fieldsets in sanity studio?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that the specific `--fieldset-bg` variable got silently deprecated recently (the move from @sanity/components to @sanity/ui). IF that's the case, [opening a bug report issue in sanity-io/sanity](https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity/issues/new/choose) repository would be great!

Regardless if that's the case, I'd suggest overwriting the css with a global selector in your `variableOverrides.css` file:

```css
div[class^="DefaultFieldset_root"] {
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

Hope this helps